# Trying to put a variable in a selector in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put a variable in a selector, but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```
<a class="button left" href="#">left</a>
<a class="button right" href="#">right</a>


$('.button:not(.disable)').show(); //Works

var oButtons = $('.button');
$(oButtons+':not(.disable)').show(); //Doesn't Work why?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because you are trying to pass a jquery object into another jquery object. what you want to do is this:

```
var oButtons = '.button';
$(oButtons+':not(.disable)').show();
```

Comment: cant i deobjectify :p oButtons ?

Comment: oButtons does not need to be a jQuery object; it just needs to be a string (as GSto's code shows). Thus, there is no need to "de-objectify" it.

Comment: The $() selector syntax only needs a string  If you want to make a jQuery object for later use, then by all means, do so...

    var Buttons = '.button';
    var oButtons = $(Buttons+':not(.disable)');
    ...
    oButtons.show();

Answer (score 2):

well you could use something like this:

```
var oButtons = $('.button');
oButtons.filter(':not(.disable)').show(); //Notice the filter option
```